# PowerShell Select-String context doesn't work with output piped from non-PowerShell command

Tags: powershell, select-string

I'm trying to use `Select-String` in PowerShell to look at the results from `docker inspect` command, but the `Context` property doesn't seem to be working properly.

As you know, `docker inspect` returns normal JSON as output, e.g.:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "c8a5810c62d8dbea11335be561522b4a3df53b9ddcae5531ae06483926c5f992",
        "Created": "2018-07-31T17:16:53.8689464Z",
        "Path": "nginx",
        "Args": [
            "-g",
            "daemon off;"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 13613,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2018-07-31T17:16:54.6460418Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

Running `sls` (alias for `Select-String`) without any additional arguments:

[image]

And running it with `Context`:

[image]

As you can see, the output is the same, and I don't see the before and after lines in my output

I'm able to use `grep` to do what I want; e.g.,

```
docker inspect devtest | grep Mounts -B 5 -A 5
```

Output of `grep`:

[image]

But I was wondering why `Select-String` doesn't work.

---

### Update

As @iRon suggested, I even tried saving the output to a file and then use `Select-String` on the file ([sample file](https://ufile.io/tuhwi)):

[image]

So, I'm really confused as to what's happening. Because for @iRon it's working properly.

---

### Update 2

I noticed that if I do something like this:

```
$result = $json | Select-String "Mounts" -Context 5`
```

then when I look at `$result[0].Context.PreContext` (and `PostContext`), they contain the before and after lines in the input, but for some unknown reason, they're not printed to the console

Comment: 1. You need to export your input file as JSON file and attach to this question
2. This question is not docker related and shall be posted to powershell forum

Comment: I do not have Docker and grep installed. Can you add (a part of) the input text and the expect output into the question?

Comment: @iRon I updated the question to include part of the output returned by the `docker inspect` command. As you see it's normal JSON, but I don't want to parse JSON and all that; I just want to use `Select-String` and be able to see the `Context`

Comment: Thanks for adding the info but it confuses me as I would expect to find the word `mount` in the `docker inspect` output example, especially knowing you do not want to parse it with a simple cmdlet as [`ConvertFro-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Yes @iRon, that's the point. In theory, I *should* be able to use `ConvertFrom-Json`, but the thing is that I don't know exactly where `Mounts` is in the hierarchy, so I thought `Select-String` would help, but my problem is that the `Context` property doesn't work here! If you check the screenshot I included for `grep`, you can see `Mounts` (I just copy pasted a few lines for brevity and to only show the shape of the output)

Answer (score 1):

As said, I do not have Docker installed (as I am on Windows 10 Home but I am currently trying to install Dock Toolbox).
Anyways, I think you should be able to exclude docker from your question by splitsing the command:

```
$Json = docker inspect devtest
$Json | Select-String "Mounts" -Context 5
```

Investigate the `$Json` string and build a [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question like:
"*How do I use `Select-String -Context` on a raw text file?*"

**Question:**

I have the following raw `Json` string:

```
$Json = @'
[
    {
        "Id": "c8a5810c62d8dbea11335be561522b4a3df53b9ddcae5531ae06483926c5f992",
        "Created": "2018-07-31T17:16:53.8689464Z",
        "Path": "nginx",
        "Args": [
            "-g",
            "daemon off;"
        ],
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/tmp/source/target",
                "Destination": "/app",
                "Mode": "ro",
                "RW": false,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 13613,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
        }
    }
]
'@
```

If I run `$Json | Select-String "Mounts" -Context 5` I do not get the expected results.

**Answer**

The [`Select-String` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) expects a stream (an array) of lines and *not* a raw text object separated by Carriage Returns and/or LineFeeds (or whatever your operating system uses for a `NewLine`).
This means that a line (a single string item in the array) could contain even a `NewLine` character but is still considered as a *single line* by the [`Select-String` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6).
In other words, the `docker inspect devtest` output is concidered as one single line by the [`Select-String` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6)

The solution is to split your text into an array of string (lines), `String[]`:

```
$Json -Split "[\r\n]+" | Select-String "Mounts" -Context 5
```

Result:

```
  "Path": "nginx",
  "Args": [
  "-g",
  "daemon off;"
  ],
> "Mounts": [
  {
  "Type": "bind",
  "Source": "/tmp/source/target",
  "Destination": "/app",
  "Mode": "ro",
```

---

Your [`test.json`](https://file.io/tpXsuC) file works fine as well:

```
Get-Content .\test.json | Select-String "Mounts" -Context 5

                  "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/232d9803e4cdb9ec031561cfae7589a43a7fdc06e0517cc3f17417e44d5174fb/diff",
                  "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/232d9803e4cdb9ec031561cfae7589a43a7fdc06e0517cc3f17417e44d5174fb/work"
              },
              "Name": "overlay2"
          },
>         "Mounts": [],
          "Config": {
              "Hostname": "c8a5810c62d8",
              "Domainname": "",
              "User": "",
              "AttachStdin": false,
```

Comment: Thank you @iRon for the answer, but I cannot get it to work, I think even with the `Split`, the output is still a single string

Comment: I made a mistake. It should probably be `-Split "[\r\n]+"`, I changed it in the answer. (btw. what OS do you use?)

Comment: Thank you again @iRon, I tried with `"[\r\n]+"`, but still `Context` doesn't work. I'm using Windows 10. There should be something from the `docker` command output. Also, I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I tried to play with your example, and it still doesn't work. I even put it in a file `test.json`, and then I do `$json = cat hello.json` and then `$json -Split "[\r\n]+" | sls Mounts -Context 5`, but no luck!
Also, I noticed that if I look at `$json[0]`, `$json[1]` etc., they contain the individual lines, so maybe it's already an array?! :(

Comment: (Presuming  `test.json` and `hello.json` are both samples), I am a little concerned by the Unix commands (as `Grep` and `Cat`) you refer to. I would use real Windows (PowerShell) commands, e.g. to write the file: `docker inspect devtest | Out-File .\test.json`, to read the file: `$json = .\test.json | get-content`. (note that [`get-content`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) returns indeed an array of strings.) I suspect an issue with character coding or NewLines chars. Can you share a sample json file somewhere?

Comment: Actually, I don't think being an array is an issue. [this is the sample file](https://file.io/y9HR8M), And this is what I do: `docker inspect c8a5810c62d8 | Out-File test.json`, then `$json = Get-Content .\test.json`.

After this, when I look at, for example, `$json[24]`, it's showing me `"HostnamePath": ...`, so I think it's already an array of strings. Don't you think so?

Comment: Yes, this one works and `Get-Content .\test.json | Select-String "Mounts" -Context 5` works as well (I  have added the results to the answer). In other words, I do not see an issue, do I miss something?

Comment: I have no idea what's happening!!! I'm going to update my question and include a screenshot of the result I get